# Minimization of two summation function

Tags: mathematical-optimization, summation

```
Remove["Global`*"];
S = 100; 
hv[1] = 3.5; hv[2] = 4;
c[1] = 10; c[2] = 50;
Cv[1] = 2.4; Cv[2] = 3;
Cf[1] = 3; Cf[2] = 1.2;
s[1] = 0.3; s[2] = 0.1;
th[1] = 0.01; th[2] = 0.03;
A[1, 1] = 3; A[2, 1] = 2; A[1, 2] = 1; A[2, 2] = 1.1;
d[1, 1] = 1850; d[2, 1] = 2000; d[1, 2] = 2100; d[2, 2] = 1300;
so[1, 1] = 3.5; so[2, 1] = 1.5; so[1, 2] = 0.3; so[2, 2] = 0.6;
t[1, 1] = 1; t[2, 1] = 1; t[1, 2] = 1; t[2, 2] = 1;
e[1, 1] = 2; e[2, 1] = 2; e[1, 2] = 2; e[2, 2] = 2;
Y[1, 1] = 3; Y[2, 1] = 3; Y[1, 2] = 3; Y[2, 2] = 3;
hb[1, 1] = 2.4; hb[2, 1] = 1.3; hb[1, 2] = 4.5; hb[2, 2] = 3.6;


  Timing[NMinimize[{\!\(\*StyleBox[UnderoverscriptBox["\[Sum]", RowBox[{"i", "=", "1"}], "2"], "Code"]\(\*StyleBox["(", "Code"]\*FractionBox[\(S*de[i]\), \(m[i]*Q[i]\)] + 
\*FractionBox[\(hv[i]*Q[i]\), \(2\)]*\((\((m[i] - 1)\)*\((1 - \*FractionBox[\(de[i]\), \(P[i]\)])\) + \*FractionBox[\(de[i]\), \(P[i]\)]\*StyleBox[")", "Code"]\)\*StyleBox["+", "Code"]
 \*FractionBox[\(de[i]\), \(m[i]*Q[i]\)]*\((m[i]*c[i] + m[i]*Q[i]*Cv[i] + Cf[i])\) + \*FractionBox[\(m[i]*s[i]*de[i]*Q[i]*th[i]\), \(2\)])\)\) + \!\(\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(j = 1\), \(2\)]\(\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(i = 1\), \(2\)]\((\*FractionBox[\(A[i, j]*d[i, j]\), \(q[i, j]\)] + 
\*FractionBox[\(hb[i, j]*\*SuperscriptBox[\((1 - k[i, j])\), \(2\)]*q[i, j]\), \(2\)] + \*FractionBox[\(k[i, j]^2*so[i, j]*q[i, j]\), \(2\)] + \*FractionBox[\(m[i]*t[i, j]*d[i, j]\), \(q[i, j]\)] + \*FractionBox[\(m[i]*e[i, j]*d[i, j]\), \(q[i, j]\)] + Y[i, j]*d[i, j])\)\)\),
Sequence @@ Flatten@Table[{Element[m[i], Integers], Q[i] = \!\(\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(i = 1\), \(2\)]\(q[i, j]\)\), D[i] = \!\(\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(i = 1\), \(2\)]\(d[i, j]\)\), 0 < k[i, j] <=1}, {{i, 1, 2}, {j, 1, 2}}]}, {Sequence @@ Flatten@Table[{m[i], k[i, j], q[i,j]}, {{i, 1, 2}, {j, 1, 2}}]}]]
```

I tried to solve this problem using nminimize...but it is not work....

What's problem with this....?

Comment: Table[...,{{i,1,2},{j,1,2}}] should probably be Table[...,{i,1,2},{j,1,2}]. D[] is a MMA function for derivative, not a user defined function, but you don't actually use the D anyway and maybe just eliminate that. Those get rid of the first wave of errors. Then you are left with the error ""The following constraints are not valid: {3400,3850,m[1] \\[Element]Integers, m[2] \\[Element]Integers,0<k[1,1],0<k[1,2],0<k[2,1],0<k[2,2],k[1,1]<=1,k[1,2]<=1,k[2,1]<=1,k[2,2]<=1,q[1,1]+q[2,1],q[1,2]+q[2,2]}." and you need to track down how you have mis-constructed your constraints.

Comment: You are assigning two different values to your Q[i], one for j==1 and one for j==2. Only the last will be remembered and used. You are not assigning values to nor minimizing  de[i] or P[i] and all variables must be assigned constant values or be being NMinimized. You are using i as a Table iterator and inside the Table as a Sum iterator. That may or may not be doing what you expect. Using separate iterator names, like i,j,k, may be less risky and perhaps easier to understand.